# training mnist data with sigmoid function return vector of 1's value

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, pattern-recognition

```
def forward(weight,inp,b):
    val=np.dot(weight.T,inp)+b
    return val

def sigmoid(x):
    val=1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-x))
    return val

def sigmoidPrime (x):
    val= x*(1-x)
    return val
```

using single input feature of image apply forward propagation then it return vector(10,1) with values. then apply sigmoid activation function it return vector(10,1) of 1,s value. then i apply sigmoidPrime function it return vector(10,1) of 0 value. And i dont need 0's value vector in perfroming backprop. please help to through out this problem...

Comment: for big enough values sigmoid's derivative is numerically a 0. make sure that your x's are not so big.

Comment: but when we take 28*28 size of image as input  and create vector x of rgb values, so in vector x value can be as 255 .. how we can reduce these value or structure to get non zero sigmoid

Comment: we usually normalize images by dividing them by 255 so your data is always in [0,1]

Comment: thanks bro.. your suggestion help me.